# Sun GridEngine job array random read file fail

Tags: sungridengine

I use SGE task array functionality to complete my job: first read a prototype, and read different data to compute. However, sometimes, when read the prototype, job fails. The error show that the prototype does not exist or complete. But I am sure the prototype file exists and is complete

```
qsub -q HTS_QUEUE -R y -r y -S /usr/bin/perl -cwd -t 1-$nphonemes Training.pl ./Config/Config.pm.2
```

The above is my command.

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the prototype is a file on some shared filesystem?

1. If that is the case one possibility is that the relevant filesystem
   isn't mounted on the node where the job runs.
2. Another possibility is that the file is on a network filesystem that
   sometimes generates transient errors for instance soft mounted NFS.  If that is the case, and you can't or don't want to modify your code to deal with the errors then you could bracket the actual code with routines that copy your prototypes and result to and from node-local storage while checking for and dealing with transient errors.  Then work on that copy.

Comment: In that case as above I would advise checking the node where the job ran to make sure it is mounted and also checking what sort of filesystem with what sort of mount options to see if it can generate transient errors.

Comment: I turn to use multiprocessing. Thank you, anyway.